# three.js - Modify the curve of a spline

Tags: javascript, three.js

So I have a scene with a camera following a spline.

This spline is created directly with three.js thanks to the `CatmullRomCurve3()` method.

As you can see on the snippet, the spline automatically creates a bumb before and after going down.

I would like to get rid of it : I want my spline to go down and flat directly (I want to keep the curve though).

I played with all the types of curve allowed (`centripetal`, `chordal` and `catmullrom`) but the bumbs are still there.

Does anyone know how can I manage to do it ? 
Thanks a lot

```js
var renderer, scene, camera, spline;

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
scene = new THREE.Scene();

renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, .1, 2000 );
      
camera.position.set(0, 0, 40);
camera.lookAt(0,0, 0);
   
spline = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3([
  new THREE.Vector3( -70, 9 ),
  new THREE.Vector3( -12, 9 ),
  new THREE.Vector3( -8, 9 ),
  new THREE.Vector3( 8, -9 ),
  new THREE.Vector3( 12, -9 ),
  new THREE.Vector3( 70, -9 ),
]);


var points = spline.getPoints(500);

var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints( points );

var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color : 0xffffff } );

// Create the final object to add to the scene
var splineObject = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );

scene.add(splineObject);
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/110/three.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

An instance of `THREE.CatmullRomCurve3` is not the correct curve type if you are looking for a linear interpolation between points. Try it with `THREE.Path` instead and by connecting your points via `.lineTo()`.

```js
var renderer, scene, camera, spline;

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
scene = new THREE.Scene();

renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 2000 );
  
camera.position.set(0, 0, 40);

var path = new THREE.Path();
path.moveTo( -70, 9 );
path.lineTo( -8, 9 );
path.lineTo( 8, - 9 );
path.lineTo( 70, -9 );

var points = path.getPoints(500);

var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints( points );

var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color : 0xffffff } );

// Create the final object to add to the scene
var splineObject = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );

scene.add(splineObject);
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/110/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe I wasn't clear enough : I do want the curve, but I don't want the bump

Comment: The bump is typical character of splines. I don't think it makes sense to use `CatmullRomCurve3` if you don't want it. Consider to use `Path` to build more complex curves which allows you to combine lines, bezier curves and splines in one curve definition.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to create that curve using Path and its methods. Out of curiosity, a path only use x and y. What if I want to have a Path using x, y and z ? Thanks very much for the help.

Comment: The classes `Path`, `Shape` and `ShapePath` always assume a 2D data space because curves are mainly used for creating 2D shapes. They are generated by triangulate a shape definition and then extruded if a 3D form is required. If you need a 3D path, I'm afraid you have to create a custom solution.